# Перезапись файла с помощью StreamWriter C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, visual-studio

Есть проблема
Определён StreamReader

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(PathManager.PathUserID))
```

В этом using есть другой блок using

```
using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(PathManager.PathUserID))
{
    List<string> userID = new List<string>();
    while ((ID = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (ID == message.Chat.Id.ToString())
        { continue; }
        userID.Add(ID);
    }
    write.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, userID));
}
```

Смысл такой: Имеется файл с ID пользователей по полю `PathManager.PathUserID`
Блок с `StreamWriter` write вызывается тогда, когда пользователь хочет отписаться от рассылки, должно происходить это следующим образом:
Список `userID` нужен для того, чтобы добавить все ID в него из файла, кроме ID того пользователя, который хочет отписаться
это как раз делает блок while, когда видит совпадающие ID, он его просто не добавляет
В конце всё записывается в файл с переносом строки с помощью `write.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, userID));`
Но происходит просто удаление всех записей из файла и всё
Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: Весьма нелепое решение. Как я понял, вы делаете аналог базы данных, только вот почему-бы не использовать уже существующее решения, да тот-же `SQLite` например, где простым простыми LINQ запросами вы без труда сделаете все правильно. Ок, не хотите базу, почему тогда не использовать сериализацию и десериализацию в таком случае? Шляться по файлу в надежде, что там ничего не собьется, ну, весьма рисковое занятие...

Comment: для проекта который я сейчас пишу решение не нелепое. вы вопрос прочитали? я спросил, как можно исправить, а не альтернативы

Comment: Наверно поэтому это не ответ, а комментарий? Вы тут не одни, придет какой-то новичок, увидит этот вопрос, и начнет у себя в асинхронном боте, где уйма запросов к базе, реализовывать ее в виде простого текстового файлика на диске, не зная что есть альтернативы. Поэтому я и пишу, что подобное решение весьма странное. Может быть вы тоже про альтернативы не знаете, яж не ведаю что у вас там в голове, верно? Так что, принимайте критику адекватно.

Comment: так зачем мне альтернативы? я спросил как исправить

Comment: информации в интернете слишком много чтобы обучать новичков по комментариям на оверфлоу, увидит в другом месте, спотыкнётся, поймёт что за ошибка и будет разбираться

Comment: что значит _Но происходит просто удаление всех записей из файла_? Какое значение `userID` перед тем как вызывается `write`? Если убрать StreamReader и оставить один StreamWriter - проблема сохраняется? Если записывать в другой файл проблема сохраняется?

Comment: Жаль, комментарии потёрли. Я бы хотел, чтобы они остались для истории. / Вы остро принимаете критику своего кода, но при этом критиковали всё сообщество. Вам можно критковать, вас нельзя критиковать? / Задайте на англоязычном сайте вопрос на _грамотном_ английском и вам точно так же предложат кучу более грамотных альтернатив (если они имеются). Задайте там вопрос на _неграмотном_ английском и вы получите от Раджеша Кумара простой как пробка, но рабочий ответ. Рабочий иногда и в узком диапазоне условий. К сожалению, большинство вопрошающих это устроит.

Comment: Вообще непонятно, зачем вы заранее открываете `writer`, когда пишете в него одной строкой в конце кода. Достаточно просто перенести это открытие райтера в конец, отдельным блоком, закрыв перед этим ридер.

Comment: Проблема решена? Дайте отклик.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Судя по вопросу на En.SO, автор начал искать альтернативу, наконец поняв что его код странный) Печально конечно, что он на Ru.SO обиделся и проигнорировал комментарии выше, но хоть получил опыт работы с En.SO)

Answer (score 3):

У файловых потоков есть множество параметров, такие как `FileShare`, `FileAccess` и другие. Чтобы один и тот же поток (stream) мог одновременно использоваться разными читателями/писателями, нужно правильно задать эти параметры.
Минимум нужно указать следующее: reader разрешает (расшаривает доступ) другим средствам писать (`FileShare.Write`) в этот же поток, а writer'у нужно явно задать доступ на запись (`FileAccess.Write`).

```
string? line;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, new FileStreamOptions { Share = FileShare.Write }))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, new FileStreamOptions { Access = FileAccess.Write }))
{
    List<string> ids = new List<string>();
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line != value)
            ids.Add(line);
    }
    writer.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ids));
}
```

Однако, если получившийся результат будет короче исходного содержимого, то в конце файла останется мусор. К тому же может влиять наличие [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)...
Подробное описание вы явно воспримете как rocket science, а вы, судя по уже удалённым комментариям, не стремитесь к звёздам.

---

Гораздо проще поступить следующим образом: открываем поток на чтение, полностью читаем, закрываем, открываем поток на запись, пишем, закрываем.
При это нет необходимости задумываться о правилах расшаривания и доступа, не будет лишнего мусора.

```
string? line;
List<string> ids = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line != value)
            ids.Add(line);
    }
}
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    writer.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ids));
}
```

---

Я бы предложил более простой способ:

```
var ids = File.ReadLines(path).Where(line => line != value).ToList();

File.WriteAllLines(path, ids);
```

но вы явно воспримете его как критику своего кода, что вы не любите...